# Calendar using enumeration

Tags: c, enums, calendar, keyboard, switch-statement

I am trying to write a program with the help of enumerations with which I can display both today and the next day. The problem is that I don't know how to enter today from the keyboard to calculate the next day. If I enter the variables in the code, it calculates correctly. I'm trying to learn C and I'm still in the beginning that's why i used some unnecessary function.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


typedef enum {jan, feb, mar, apr, may, jun, jul, aug, sep, oct, nov, dec} month;


int day_today(month m, int i)
{
    int day_of_month;
    switch (m)
    {
        case jan: printf("january %d \n", i);
                  day_of_month = 31;
                  break;
        case feb: printf("february %d \n", i);
                  day_of_month = 28;
                  break;
        case mar: printf("march %d \n", i);
                  day_of_month = 31;
                  break;
        case apr: printf("april %d \n", i);
                  day_of_month = 30;
                  break;
        case may: printf("may %d \n", i);
                  day_of_month = 31;
                  break;
        case jun: printf("june %d \n", i);
                  day_of_month = 30;
                  break;
        case jul: printf("jule %d \n", i);
                  day_of_month = 31;
                  break;
        case aug: printf("august %d \n", i);
                  day_of_month = 31;
                  break;
        case sep: printf("september %d \n", i);
                  day_of_month = 30;
                  break;
        case oct: printf("pctomber %d \n", i);
                  day_of_month = 31;
                  break;
        case nov: printf("november %d \n", i);
                  day_of_month = 30;
                  break;
        case dec: printf("december %d \n", i);
                  day_of_month = 31;
                  break;
        default: printf("Error at input month \n");
    }
    return day_of_month;
}

month next_month(month m)
{
        return(m+1%12);
}

int next_day(int d)
{
    return(d+1);
}

int main()
{
    month a_month = feb ;
    int d = 28 ;
    int day_of_month;
    //printf("Give the month and day: ");
    //scanf("%c %d\n", &a_month, &d);
    day_of_month = day_today(a_month, d);
    if (d >= day_of_month)
        {
            a_month = next_month(a_month);
            d = 1;
        }
    else d = next_day(d);
    printf( day_today(a_month,d));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have the user enter the month number, starting from 0.

Comment: It doesn't work. It gives me the default switch statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the error checking for the user's date input as well. It must be within `[1,max_day_of_month]`. The current date should not be printed without this check.

Here is one of the implementation which checks for input date.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


typedef enum {jan, feb, mar, apr, may, jun, jul, aug, sep, oct, nov, dec} month;

void isValidDate(int day_of_month,int d, char* s)
{
    if(d>=1 && d<=day_of_month)
        printf("%s %d\n",s,d);
}

int day_today(month m, int i)
{
    int day_of_month;
    switch (m)
    {
        case jan: day_of_month = 31; 
                  isValidDate(day_of_month,i,"january");
                  break;
        case feb: day_of_month = 28;
                  isValidDate(day_of_month,i,"february");
                  break;
        case mar: day_of_month = 31;
                  isValidDate(day_of_month,i,"march");
                  break;
        case apr: day_of_month = 30;
                  isValidDate(day_of_month,i,"april");
                  break;
        case may: day_of_month = 31;
                  isValidDate(day_of_month,i,"may");
                  break;
        case jun: day_of_month = 30;
                  isValidDate(day_of_month,i,"june");
                  break;
        case jul: day_of_month = 31;
                  isValidDate(day_of_month,i,"july");
                  break;
        case aug: day_of_month = 31;
                  isValidDate(day_of_month,i,"august");
                  break;
        case sep: day_of_month = 30;
                  isValidDate(day_of_month,i,"september");
                  break;
        case oct: day_of_month = 31;
                  isValidDate(day_of_month,i,"octomber");
                  break;
        case nov: day_of_month = 30;
                  isValidDate(day_of_month,i,"november");
                  break;
        case dec: day_of_month = 31;
                  isValidDate(day_of_month,i,"december");
                  break;
        default: printf("Error at input month \n");
    }
    return day_of_month;
}

month next_month(month m)
{
        return((m+1)%12);
}

int next_day(int d)
{
    return(d+1);
}

int main()
{
    month a_month = 1 ;
    int d = 28 ;
    
    printf("Give the month and day: ");
    scanf("%u %d", &a_month, &d);
    int day_of_month = day_today(a_month, d);
    if (d > day_of_month)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"Invalid Date");
        return -1;
    }
    else if(d == day_of_month)
    {
        a_month = next_month(a_month);
        d = 1;
    }
    else
        d = next_day(d);

    printf("Next, a_month = %d, d = %d\n",a_month,d);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice and implementation of the code

Answer (score 0):

Your scanf is wrong, try:

```
scanf("%d", &a_month);
```